# Sort a list of tuples by their second element without higher order functions or recursion

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, minimum

I have a list of `(String, Int)` pairs and am struggling to figure out how to sort the list by the `snd` field (`Int`). I am not allowed to use higher order functions or recursion which makes it more difficult.

For example, I have

```
[("aaaaa", 5),("bghdfe", 6),("dddr",4)]
```

and would like to sort it into

```
 [("dddr",4),("aaaaa", 5),("bghdfe", 6)].
```

*Edit:*
I understand that the sort may not be possible without higher order functions, what I really need is to find the element with the minimum length (the `snd` field), so is there a way to find the minimum number and then take the `fst` field of the list's element at that index? If that way works better I am unsure about how to find the index of  that minimum number however.

Comment: The minimum length of what?

Comment: What can you actually use? Without recursion and higher order functions it looks impossible, unless there's some allowed way to implicitly invoke HO functions. For instance, list comprehensions can effectively replace `map`, `filter`, `concatMap`. The same holds for `do`-notation. Is either allowed? On top of that, is the library `sort` function allowed?

Comment: each Int is the length of the string, so the smallest int = the minimum length - I need to find the smallest string in a list of strings

Comment: 'Use basic functions, list comprehension, and library functions, but not recursion' - sort is not allowed

Comment: And you may not use `minimumBy` or `foldl` or `sort`?

Answer (score 2):

The task seems to be impossible, since you can't write a sort without recursion in Haskell. This means, you must use `sort`, which is usually something like `sortBy compare` and thus you have it.

But if you are allowed to use `sort` you can do it by first reversing all tuples, sorting the resulting list and reversing the tuples in the result again. This should be possible to do in a few nested list comprehension, so technically no higher order functions are needed.

---

After you have given more details, I'd do

```
homework list = snd (minimum [ (s,f) | (f,s) <- list ])
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that reversing the list of tuples and doing it like that would be more complicated but is in fact far more elegant - this solves my problem perfectly

Comment: `minimum [(2,10),(2,2)]` => `(2,2)` but we should probably be returning the first one, as `minimumBy (comparing fst)` would. IOW for the input of `[("bbb", 3), ("aaa", 3)]` your function returns `"aaa"`, where I'd expect `"bbb"` to be expected as the return value. (although it's not clear) :)

Comment: @WillNess you're probably right, but the task is not fully clear anyways. For example it said `("aaa", 5)` but 5 is not the length of `"aaa"`

Comment: still, using `minimum` that way is a nice find. `minimumBy` would be using a HOF, but that way, not. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without higher order functions or recursion all you have left, technically, is list comprehensions. Thus we define

```
-- sortBy (comparing snd) >>> take 1 >>> listToMaybe >>> fmap fst
--  ~= minimumBy (comparing snd) >>> fst
foo :: Ord b => [(a,b)] -> Maybe a
foo xs = case [ a | (a,b) <- xs
                  , null [ () | (_c,d) <- xs, d < b]]
         of (a:_) -> Just a
            []    -> Nothing
```

Comment: I beleive there could be no less complex complete solution, so it must be that the task-giving professor is either a sadist or wants to make clear how important recursion and HOFs are.

Comment: BTW I believe even `sort` could be written in this torturous way, with lots and lots of LCs. maybe making it cubic, who knows.